# Industry standard for implementing application branding?

Tags: c#, branding

I am currently doing prototypes to add localization and branding support to our applications. Currently, I have been able to successfully make use of the localization framework and custom cultures to support both localization and branding.

Custom cultures enables me to have, say, an "en-US-BrandA" resource DLL which contains brand specific resources for the "en-US" language for "BrandA". I can also create a "ja-JP-BrandB" resource DLL to accomplish the same but this time for the "ja-JP" language and "BrandB".

So far, I have not found any standard practices for applying application branding. Ultimately, what I want to accomplish is to not tie in localization and branding together. As with the example above, the cultures are mainly used to apply branding but it does not necessarily relate to branding at all.

I might have missed something so if anyone has or is currently doing application branding, it would be great if you can share what you have come-up with or had already implemented in your application. I would like to determine if my approach to localization and branding is a good idea or not.

TIA.