# Change resource files using command line build arguments

Tags: c#, .net

I have an application that needs to be released under two separate brands. To do this I need to have some different images, and strings throughout the applications, such as in the about dialogue.

My initial thought was to have separate folders under my resources directory with the same files for each brand, including a resx file with string constants to use. Then I would use an argument to change a Property in my csproj file that would change the path to the resource files.

Will this work? Is there a better way to handle this?

Example of my thoughts:

Project file:

```
<PropertyGroup>
   <BRAND>DefaultBrand</BRAND>
</PropertyGroup>

<EmbeddedResource Include="Resources\$(BRAND)\branding.resx" />
<Compile Include="Resources\$(BRAND)\branding.Designer.cs" />

<ItemGroup>
  <None Include="Resources\DefaultBrand\BG.png" />
  <None Include="Resources\OtherBrand\BG.png" />
</ItemGroup
```

Program.cs:

```
ResourceManager rm = new ResourceManager("branding", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
String companyName = rm.GetString("COMPANY_NAME");
```

Build Commands:

```
MSBuild MSBuild.xml /t:Compile
MSBuild MSBuild.xml /t:Compile /p:BRAND=OtherBrand
```

Comment: Is the application localized for each brand? Or is it one language?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36582901/how-to-do-extreme-branding-internationalization-in-net

Comment: It will not be localized and has just one language

Comment: Can't you dedicate one language to each brand and simply switch the culture on the UI thread? That wouldn't require fiddling with the build files and works out of the box, including IDE support.

Comment: Not sure how well that would work with image resources and such. That would also make things more complicated in the future if we do decide to localize the project.